# Keep top UiTableViewCell from scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a tableView and im using the first cell to be a filter button for the table. once clicked the UiPickerView comes up.

Is there a way to keep that first cell from scrolling with the rest of the table and stay static under the nav bar?

my table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString * teamCellIndentifier   = @"allEventsCell";
static NSString * filterCell            = @"filterCell";
UIColor *separator                      = [UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0f green:220/255.0f blue:223/255.0f alpha:1];
UIColor *subtitle                       = [UIColor colorWithRed:100/255.0f green:100/255.0f blue:100/255.0f alpha:1];

if(indexPath.row != 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:teamCellIndentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:teamCellIndentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.font                     = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor          = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor     = kPointstreakBlueColor;
    cell.textLabel.textColor                = subtitle;
    cell.accessoryType                      = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.detailTextLabel.font                 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor      = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.highlightedTextColor = kPointstreakBlueColor;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor            = subtitle;

    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:separator];

    VideoClipData   * gameVideos    = [gameJsondataEventAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    VideoClip       * gameVideoData = [gameEventAry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // date formatting
    NSString        * str           = gameVideoData.evtCreatedSrt;
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormat    = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale        * usLocale      = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

    [dateFormat setLocale:usLocale];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate * dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY - hh:mma"];

    cell.textLabel.text = gameVideos.evtTitleStr;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:dte]];

    return cell;
}
else
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:filterCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:filterCell];
    }

    if(self.toggle == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.font                     = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0];
        cell.backgroundColor                    = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor     = kPointstreakBlueColor;
        cell.textLabel.textColor                = subtitle;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment            = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Filter Events";
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.textColor     = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.textLabel.text          = @"Cancel";
        return cell;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for looking!

UPDATE:

I was able to make a clickable header like so:

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView * headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 22)];
    UILabel* headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, tableView.frame.size.width - 5, 18);
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    headerLabel.text = @"Filter Evnets";
    headerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bringUpPickerViewWithRow:)];
    [headerLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return headerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 70;
}
```

Comment: If you only have one section in your table view, you could use a section header for that. It will stay pinned to the top of the table .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make it your section header, not the first cell. If you have more than one section, you will want it to be its own view (not a part of the table view).